# How to make lmv wait sda5_crypt AND sdb_crypt unlock on boot?

Tags: boot, lvm, luks

I have two HDs in my PC, sda and sdb with a clean Ubuntu installation with LVM and LUKS encryption on sda. I want to increase the root size extending it on sdb with encryption too.

I managed to create a new LUKS partition "sdb_crypt" on sdb and added it in /etc/crypttab so I can unlock it on boot. It works fine.

Now I create a physical LVM volume on sdb_crypt and I vgextend ubuntu-vg with it, then I lvextend and resize2fs the root. I can see the new root size with df -h.

On reboot LVM loads before sdb_crypt unlock, it fails and system goes to BusyBox (initramfs).

I can't understand how to make LVM wait for sdb_crypt unlock.

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When do you have sdb_crypt set to unlock? Do you enter the passwords for both sda_crypt and sdb_crypt together?

Comment: This seems to be an issue for more than just ubuntu: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=807600

Comment: This question is quite interesting to me because I also have multiple drives on LUKS LVM systems, however I have my second drive set to unlock with credentials stored in the first drive's crypt setup. I'll try messing around with a dual-disk VM and bridging the LUKS volumes, but I'm not an expert. Really wishing gparted had proper LVM/LUKS support right now.